# Calling super method from within an anonymous inner class inside the overridden method

Tags: java, class

Imagine we have a class:

```
class A {
  public void m() {
     System.out.println("A - > m()");
  }
}
```

...and I want to override the method `m` on class creation **without** making a second subclass `B` to extend `A`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A() {
        @Override
        public void m() {
            System.out.println("Override - > m()");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // I want to be able to call the super method.
                   // This is illegal!
                   A.super.m();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    };
    a.m();
}
```

Currently my solution is to create a private method that calls the `super.m()`

```
   A a = new A() {

        private void superMethod() {
            super.m();
        }

        @Override
        public void m() {
            System.out.println("Overrided - > m()");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    superMethod();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    };
    a.m();
```

I want to know why I am not able to write `A.super.m()` and if there another way to perform this task.

Comment: Could a [local class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) suit your needs?

Comment: Well it could, but that was actually what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I want to know why I am not able to write `A.super.m()`...

This is because `A` is in fact *not* a directly enclosing class. The directly enclosing class of the `Runnable` is `new A() { ... }` which is an anonymous subclass of `A`.

In other words, if you would have had

```
class A extends Base {
    new Runnable() { ... }
}
```

then `A.super` would have worked, but now you have

```
class <Anonymous subclass of A> extends A {
    new Runnable() { ... }
}
```

which means that something like `A.super` isn't possible, since there's no syntax for `<Anonymous subclass of A>.super.m`.

> ...and, is there another way to perform this task.

The way you've solved it is reasonable in my opinion. Another way would be to create a local subclass of `A` (just to introduce an identifier to use in `____.super.m`) as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    class SubA extends A {
        @Override
        public void m() {
            System.out.println("Override - > m()");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SubA.super.m();
                 // ^^^^ we now have a name of the directly enclosing class
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
    A a = new SubA();
    a.m();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Writing A.super.m(), suppose that A has a superclass with a m method.
But in your code, you don't specify a superclass, and by default, the only superclass you have is Object.
But Object class doesn't have a 'm' method, so you could not call it.
A good way to do something like that is to use design pattern, like decorator.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow... new A() { ... } has super class A, no?

Comment: if i don't make a mistake yes :)

Comment: Reading your answer, it looks like you're saying that A doesn't have a super class with method m. I can't see how that is related. The error message you get when trying to compile this code is not that Object lacks method m, but that A.this isn't a valid expression.

Comment: in the first case A.super.m() is not possible cause you have no instance of object A.

Comment: Uhm... new A() { ... } create's an instance of A.

Comment: you cannot call super outside of an instance method.
And new A(){...} create an instance of Test$1 like manouti explain above not a "real" instance of A.

Comment: new A() { ... } does create an instance of A. I'm not sure what you mean by "real" instance. It's a subclass, sure, but what you're saying is similar to *If you're creating a Dog you're not creating a "real" Animal.*

Comment: I'd say that you're definitely creating a real Animal if you do new Dog().

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there would be a  simpler way to do it other than the way you already have it.

The problem is that the anonymous class `A` itself (not the base class `A`) cannot be referenced inside the `Runnable` class. The anonymous class is represented as something like `package.A$1` when compiled to its own class file. For example, when you call `superMethod` inside the `run` of the thread, the following bytecode is executed:

```
getfield mypackage/Test$1$1/this$1 Lmypackage/Test$1;
invokestatic mypackage/Test$1/access$0(Lmypackage/Test$1;)V
```

In order to reference its base class `A`, there is no reference to this inner class instance so that you call the `super.m()` expression.